# CodeIgniter Tank Auth Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

I can't seem to get tank auth installed correctly, I copied over the files, but everytime I visit 'localhost/auth' it gives me the error `Unable to load the requested class: security`.

The documentation I've been able to find is very light, and doesn't cover this error (or how to install it).  I am installing on a windows box running WAMP.  But am planning to move it to a linux box running apache after development.

Thoughts?

Comment: I was able to pin it down to tankauth trying to load a library called security.

Comment: Also, I am running on CI 2.0.1

Comment: just remove the line which load the security class ..its loaded by default..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem on latest codeigniter 2.1.0

Commenting the `$this->load->library('security');` from auth.php controller will remove the error. Codeigniter 2.1.0 has security class automatically loading at the core.

I have updated my repo with the changes, hope someone finds it useful, https://bitbucket.org/mtsandeep/tank-auth-with-roles/overview